# vscode jupyter notebook: Session cannot genreate requests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've been using vscode with Jupyter notebook extension (now maintain by Microsoft) for two years but It's weird to encouter the problem never met before as the error said:

```
Error: Session cannot generate requests
at S.executeCodeCell (c:\Users\alex0\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599\out\client\extension.js:66:301742)
at S.execute (c:\Users\alex0\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599\out\client\extension.js:66:300732)
at S.start (c:\Users\alex0\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599\out\client\extension.js:66:296408)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at t.CellExecutionQueue.executeQueuedCells (c:\Users\alex0\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599\out\client\extension.js:66:312326)
at t.CellExecutionQueue.start (c:\Users\alex0\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.10.1101450599\out\client\extension.js:66:311862)
```

The problem shows when I train the CNN model. The model I've built previously bumped into this problem, but it works fine when preparing other deep learning models. What I've tried:

1. Install `anaconda,` use its kernel.
2. re-install Jupyter notebook extension and re-open vscode.
3. run vscode as administrator.

All of them get no luck. The script has been tested and run sucessfully on Google Colab, and it's the alternative I am using now. Is there any way I can fix it?

Other information:

1. windows 11
2. vscode version: 1.62.3
3. jupyter notebook extention: v2021.10.1101450599
4. anaconda with its Python 3.9.6 version package
5. Python(self-installed): 3.9.7

I'll provide extra information if necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely your kernel is crashing for some reason. Can you log an issue here?
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues.

Comment: Thanks, I realized I've installed Nvidia cuDNN for using Tensorflow Mirrored Strategy. However, it seems there's a bug with multi-processing. I don't know whether it's related, but previous using my old laptop, no issue running the notebook, without cuDNN.

Answer (score 0):

Download zlibwapi.dll from https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-zlib-windows and put it under the directory "C:\Program Files\Nvidia GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\vxx.x\bin" Make sure the path is added to your environment variables.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).